# Is the application of Lebesgue DCT valid here?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

*Problem:*

Let $f_n: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of measurable functions.

Suppose that $\int_{0}^{1}|f_n(x)|^2 ~ dx \le 1$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f_n$ converges to $0$ a.e.

Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) ~ dx = 0$.

*Question:* **Is the following solution correct? If not, how can it be fixed?**

*Proposed Solution:*

We have $\|f_n\|_{L^2} \le 1$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and the measure space is sigma-finite. So $\|f_n\|_{L^1} \le \|f_n\|_{L^2} \le 1$ and $f_n$ is bounded above by the integrable function $g(x) = 1$ for every $n$. By the pointwise-a.e. convergence, $f \equiv 0$, and $|f| \le g$. So by DCT, the result follows.

Comment: This application of DCT is invalid. You need a function $g$ such that $\lvert f_n \rvert \le g$ and you do not have this; instead you have $\|f_n\|_{L^2} \le 1$, but $f_n$ could still get large in places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to solve the problem. Since $f_n\to 0$ a.e, and the measure space is finite, you have $f_n\to 0$ in probability. Given $\epsilon>0$, let $A_n=\{|f_n|>\epsilon\}$. Then
$$
\int_0^1 |f_n|\,dx=\int_{A_n} |f_n|\,dx + \int_{[0,1]\setminus A_n}|f_n|\,dx\le \int_0^1 f_n(x){\bf 1}_{A_n}(x)\,dx + \epsilon
$$
Now apply Cauchy-Schwarz to that last integral.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is false. DCT requires that the function be dominated in the sense that $|f_{n}| \leq g$.

Also, the inequalities that you use don't apply in a sigma finite measure space. They apply in a finite measure space! They are false over the entire real line!

Comment: Yes, but we're in a finite measure space here, so the $L^1$-$L^2$ inequality is fine.

Comment: I agree. But in the proof, you (EDIT: the op) justify this via sigma finite-ness. The issue is that you used the wrong justification.

Comment: Sure, not me, but I agree the OP used the wrong statement. Still I'm pretty sure this property holds (i.e., it is true that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int^1_0 f_n(x) dx =0$), just the proof is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry. I assumed that you were OP. Sorry I didn't read before posting. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: As for the proof: I think that I have the idea. I'll post it after thinking for ab it.